# Smartphone as Authenticator in WebAuthn

Tags: authentication, web, smartphone, google-authenticator, webauthn

I am wondering how do I use my smartphone as Authenticator in WebAuthn, Is there any live demo that can help me to understand more about that technology!!
thank you in advance

Comment: There seems to be an API offered by HYPR -> https://www.hypr.com/decentralized-authentication/  but I couldn't find more myself yet. No app or anything, just USB keys you would attach to your phone, just like on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome70 now has support the "publicKey" encryption, ie. biometry on devices and laptops.

Demo site https://webauthndemo.appspot.com/

Works, I tested in on my phone using Chrome 70 beta

Comment: I have the same question - other than using a USB key dongle in my smartphone I haven't found an answer either. I guess the answer would be some kind of app that f.ex. uses the fingerprint reader to generate or read a private key.

Comment: but still doesn't support on Chrome for iOS 13, 14. `https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1101804`

Comment: @ThangLe iOS only supports Webkit browser engines. Apple does this to slow the progress of web standards to protect their money making machine (app store). No competing browser engines allowed. Chrome on iOS is just a skinned Safari. It amazes me how they can get away with that when MS and Google get fined for minor stuff in comparison. Money talks I guess